# Hide TabGroup / TabBar

Tags: android-tabs, titanium-android

I've tried multiple methods to hide this tab:

[image: http://imgur.com/tUmWAHP]

Following are the methods I've used:

```
tabGroup.hide()  
tabBar.hide()   
tabGroupHidden: true   
tabBarHidden: true   
tabGroup.setNavBarHidden()   
tabGroup.NAVIGATION_METHOD_STANDARD   
visible: false   
mainWindow.tabGroup = hidden
```

And this is the current code as it sits now:

```
var mainWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Title',
    layout:'vertical',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    tabGroupHidden:true
});
mainWindow.add(Helpers.buildNavTableView(mainNavItems));
// Tab Group
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({ 
    tabGroupHidden:true
});
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    tabGroupHidden:true,
    window:mainWindow
});
tabGroup.addTab(tab1); 
// open tab group
tabGroup.hide();
tabGroup.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a simple window and open it

```
var win=Ti.UI.createWindow()
win.open();
```

Thanks

Comment: That does not work... please give me a serious solution please.

Answer (score 0):

We can Hide TabGroup / TabBar then write below code
`final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(actionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);`